# создание таблицы в MSSQL с помощью python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь создать таблицу , если она не существует таким образом

```
with conn:
        cursor.execute("""IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='register' AND xtype='U')
        CREATE TABLE register (name TEXT ,time TEXT)""")
cursor.close()
```

но таблица не создается. И в консоли ошибок не вижу.
при этом в sqllite3

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `register` (`name` STRING ,`time` STRING )")
```

создает без проблем.

Comment: Сам запрос - корректный. Это может быть косяк коннектора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```python
tab_name = "dbo.register"
sql = f"""
IF OBJECT_ID(N'{tab_name}', N'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE {tab_name} (name TEXT, time TEXT);
END;
"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```

PS в SQL Server лучше использовать тип данных `varchar(<n> chars)` вместо `text`

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало